# "kpl-daemon-0000" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Exception when using aws kinesis

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, protocol-buffers

How to resolve the below error which I get in start up when using aws kinesis library. I am using current google protobuf version 3.11.4

```
Exception in thread "kpl-daemon-0000" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.addAll(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/util/List;)V
      at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.protobuf.Config$Configuration$Builder.addAllAdditionalMetricDims(Config.java:3615)
      at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducerConfiguration.additionalConfigsToProtobuf(KinesisProducerConfiguration.java:223)
      at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducerConfiguration.toProtobufMessage(KinesisProducerConfiguration.java:1415)
      at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.startChildProcess(Daemon.java:435)
      at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$100(Daemon.java:63)
      at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$1.run(Daemon.java:133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the version to 3.13.0 and it got resolved